Unknown red wire in ceiling
I am replacing a ceiling fan, which I have done before. However, I have never come across this exact scenario. My ceiling box has a grouping of white wires, a grouping of black wires, and a single red wire. Why do I not have a green/copper ground wire and why do I have a red wire?
I have added pics of the switch wiring. I believe the black wires in the ceiling were not being used before because if they had been attached to anything when the previous ceiling fan was removed, the wire nut would not still be attached.[![light switch 1] 

Please add a second photo, like this one, but of the box where the switch is for this light/fan.   You might find a cable there with red/white/black, and white probably not used.  Try to unravel wires enough without disconnecting anything, to make it clear what wires belong to what cables.

I added more pics and a thought.

It seems the ground wires are bonded together at the bottom.
The red wire is most likely a switched hot from the wall switch.
Newer code requires a neutral wire at the switch box(usually capped/not used) so you have a /3 cable of black, red and white, instead of the old style switch loops that used only black and white, with white as hot and connected to the hot in the ceiling.
Check the switch and should see a matching red wire on the switch.

The ground wires really should have a wire nut on them rather than just being twisted together. That can, in addition,  be used to add a bare or green ground pigtail to connect to the fixture.

It appears as though the cable from the switch to the light is being used to pass both switched and unswitched power between the two boxes.  We cannot tell from the pictures which way it's going.   Both boxes appear to tee unswitched power off to other locations.
If the source of power is at the ceiling, it goes both to the switch box and to other places via the third cable there.  At the switch box it also goes to other places, and sends switched power back to the ceiling via the red cable.
If the source of power is at the switch box, it sends switched and unswitched power to the ceiling and also unswitched power to other locations.  In the ceiling the unswitched power is also being fed elsewhere.
Where are the grounds?  In the ceiling with the wires unraveled you can see them.  These are unfortunately short.  They need to be joined with a wire nut and they also need to provide a ground wire to the light fixture.  You should untwist them, carefully not to break them, and use a Wago 221-415 to rejoin them and also provide a ground tail for your light fixture.  I'm recommending the lever nut so you don't have to retwist them and risk making them even shorter.  In the switch box the ground wires are probably hidden at the back.  Same procedure for you there.
Another problem is the switch is being used to pass power from its source to other fixtures through both the backstab and the screw terminal.  Those two black wires should be joined with a wire nut, and a third short wire from that to the switch using the screw terminal.
